# Multiple Git submodules sharing same subfolder?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, multiple-repositories

I'm about to ship some libraries, and want to produce something like the following:

```
Project
└─ Assets
   ├─ Plugins
   ├─ Scripts
   └─ AwesomeLibraries
      ├─ One
      ├─ Two
      ├─ Three
      ├─ Four
      ├─ Five
      └─ Six
```

And version the libraries only (for sake of example), like this:

**Main repository** to maintain submodules (checked out into 'Project/Assets')

```
/
```

**Submodule 1** (checked out into 'Project/Assets'):

```
AwesomeLibraries
├─ One
├─ Two
└─ Three
```

**Submodule 2** (checked out into 'Project/Assets'):

```
AwesomeLibraries
├─ Four
└─ Five
```

**Submodule 3** (checked out into 'Project/Assets'):

```
AwesomeLibraries
└─ Six
```

**Is there a way to setup such repository structure?** Some gitignore tweak? Or is there some other git concept out there? Something "maintainable".

**You may ask why:** Submodule 1 contains the open sourced libraries, users should check out into their `Project/Assets` folder. Further submodules contains the closed sourced / monetizing libraries, while users should also check out into `Project/Assets` folder, like the rest of the libraries, while everything should be lined up in a `Project/Assets/AwesomeLibraries` folder (kind of "amutomatically").

Comment: Why aren't you just using a dependency/package manager like npm or composer? To me, the name "library" implies no development going on through the project - which is the only time you should be using submodules or even subtrees. Unless you plan to distribute these "libraries" with intentions of them being developed together, then just package them separately and require them as a dependency in the project.

Comment: Actually I do that. I mean Unity has some sort of package manager solution. I released most of the libraries there aleady.

Comment: **The repository structure would mainly used by me during development.** Libraries can be best developed in context of client projects, this is the way I shape libraries. I usually checkout my libraries into every client project I work on, and add / remove library stuff throughout the course of development. I don't want to maintain separate project for each tool I make. I'd like to have them all nearby at hand, and extract reusables from the project on the fly (also can see instantly if something break).

Comment: I can always setup a `.gitignore` for each (exclude everything, but include library folder / subfolders)... ...but I find it cumbersome indeed.